# How to fail gradle build when no tests where executed/found?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to fail the build when no tests where found or executed.

e.g. when useJUnitPlatform is not defined and test classes exists. The build finish successfully even if no tests are executed. In this case i would like that the build fails. I also tried to set failOnNoMatchingTests but it didn't work...

```
test {
//  useJUnitPlatform()
    getFilter().failOnNoMatchingTests(true)
}
```

Does sombody has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using afterSuite ([afterSuite](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterSuite(groovy.lang.Closure))) for this, the following worked for me -

```
test {
    //useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
         afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if(result.testCount == 0)
                    throw new GradleException("No tests were executed. Build failed.")
        }
    }
}
```

As `useJunitPlatform()` is not executed here, you will see the GradleException being thrown. I modified the original solution from here - [Print gradle tests](https://gist.github.com/orip/4951642)